# Как убрать белое "сверкание" под клавиатурой при параметре "adjustResize "

Tags: java, android

Всем доброго времени суток! Появилась такая проблема у меня есть EditText в нем много разного текста. Мне нужно сфокусировать курсор на месте нажатия, что бы клавиатура не перекрывала текст, для этого я указал параметр в манифесте

```
    <activity
        android:name=".NewEntryActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Но из-за этого появилась такая проблема, при загрузке клавиатуры возникает белое "сверкание". На словах мало что понятно, записал короткое видео, можно посмотреть [тут](https://vk.com/niks43russ?z=video256971608_456239289%2Fvideos256971608%2Fpl_256971608_-2), о чем вообще идет речь. Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу это исправить?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    tools:context="com.example.nick.notebookofthepoet.NewEntryActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: А покажите xml разметку экрана. Может попробовать ставить бекграунд у самого нижнего слоя в такой же цвет, как у EditText?

Answer (score 0):

При `adjustResize` элементы разметки меняют свой размер при появлении клавиатуры. Так как это происходит моментально, а клавиатура появляется с анимацией, то некоторое время под цветным `EditText` виден белый бекграунд лейаута.

Установите бекграунд у нижнего слоя лейауте в цвет `EditText` и "сияние" должно стать незаметным.

Например, ставим красный цвет:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Благодарю, разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить в imeOptions EditText флаги: flagNoFullscreen, flagNoExtractUi.

Comment: не получилось, так же все.